# program not recognizing multiple occurrences of word python (on linux)

Tags: python, markov-chains

I'm making an essay generator by creating a directed graph from sample text where the words are nodes and there are directed edges between a word and any word that follows it. I'm forming the nodes through a dictionary, but the program doesn't seem to read occurrences of a word after the first.

```
tH = {}
with open('ex','r') as f:
  for line in f:
    valHold = [w.lower() for w in line.split()]
for x in valHold:
  if x not in tH:
    tH[x] = []
    if x != valHold[-1] and valHold[valHold.index(x) + 1] not in tH[x]:
     tH[x].append(valHold[valHold.index(x) + 1])
print(tH)
```

I expect the output to be

```
{'the' : ['sun', 'moon'], 'sun' : ['the'], 'moon' : []}
```

when the file 'ex' contains the string

```
'the sun the moon'
```

but instead the output is

```
{'the' : ['sun'], 'sun' : ['the'] 'moon' : []}
```

Comment: `if x not in tH:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `for x in valHold:` which iterates through each word in valHold, you'll need to iterates through every second word ie x = valHold[0](store valHold[1]),x =valHold[2](store valHold[3]) and so on.
You could do this:

```
for i in range(0, len(valHold), 2):
    x = valHold[i]
    if x not in tH:
        tH[x] = []
    if x != valHold[-1] and valHold[i + 1] not in tH[x]:
        tH[x].append(valHold[i + 1])
```